# Can you outgolf me? (Cops section)

Tags: code-challenge, number, sequence, cops-and-robbers

## Cops section

The robbers section can be found [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/88981/34388).

<sup>Thanks to **FryAmTheEggman**, **Peter Taylor**, **Nathan Merrill**, **xnor**, **Dennis**, **Laikoni** and **Mego** for their contributions.</sup>

---

#### Challenge

Your task is to write 2 different programs ([full programs/functions/etc.](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/2422/34388)) in the **same** language and the **same** version (e.g. Python 3.5 ≠ Python 3.4, so that is not allowed), and when given **n** (using [STDIN/function arguments/etc.](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2447/34388)), compute **a(n)** where **a** is an OEIS sequence of your choice. One of those programs is shorter than the other. You only need to submit the *longer* program of the two. The other one needs to be saved in case of not being cracked after 7 days. Your submission is cracked when your program has been outgolfed (whether it is by 1 byte or more).

For example, if the task you chose was to perform **2 × *n***, this could be a valid submission (in Python 2):

> ### Python 2, 16 bytes, score = 15 / 16 = 0.9375
>
> ```
> print(2*input())
> ```
>
> Computes [A005843](https://oeis.org/A005843), (offset = 0).

If your submission has been cracked, then you need to state that in your header like so:

> ### Python 2, 16 bytes, score = 15 / 16 = 0.9375, [cracked] + link
>
> ```
> print(2*input())
> ```
>
> Computes [A005843](https://oeis.org/A005843), (offset = 0).

---

#### Offset

This can be found on every OEIS page. For example, for [A005843](https://oeis.org/A005843), the offset is `0,2`. We only need to use the first one, which is `0`. This means that the function is defined for all numbers ≥ 0.

In other words, the function OEIS(n) starts with **n = 0**. Your program needs to work for all cases given by OEIS.

More information can be found [here](http://oeis.org/wiki/Offsets).

---

#### Scoring

The score you get for your submission is equal to the following formula:

**Score** = **Length (in bytes) of secret code** ÷ **Length (in bytes) of public code**

The example above has the score 15 ÷ 16 = 0.9375.

The submission with the **lowest** score wins. Only submissions that have posted their solution will be eligible for winning.

---

#### Rules

- The task you need to do is an OEIS sequence of your choice.
- Given **n**, output **OEIS(n)**. Deviation is **not** allowed, so you need to produce the exact same sequence (when given n, you need to output OEIS(n)).
- Submissions that are not cracked within a period of 7 days are considered **safe** after the **solution has been posted** (submissions older than 7 days that do not have their solution posted are still vulnerable in being cracked).
- In your submission, you need to post the following things: **language name**, **byte count**, **full code**, so no pastebin links etc. (to prevent answers like Unary), **OEIS sequence**, **score with lengths of both programs** and additionally, the encoding that is used.
- Note: the same sequence **cannot** be posted twice in the *same* language. (For example, if the sequence A005843 has been done in Pyth, you cannot use Pyth again for that same sequence.)
- Input and output are both in decimal (base 10)

#### Leaderboard

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script><style>table th,table td{padding: 5px;}th{text-align: left;}.score{text-align: right;}table a{display: block;}.main{float: left;margin-right: 30px;}.main h3,.main div{margin: 5px;}.message{font-style: italic;}#api_error{color: red;font-weight: bold;margin: 5px;}</style> <script>QUESTION_ID=88979;var safe_list=[];var uncracked_list=[];var n=0;var bycreation=function(x,y){return (x[0][0]<y[0][0])-(x[0][0]>y[0][0]);};var byscore=function(x,y){return (x[0][1]>y[0][1])-(x[0][1]<y[0][1]);};function u(l,o){jQuery(l[1]).empty();l[0].sort(o);for(var i=0;i<l[0].length;i++) l[0][i][1].appendTo(l[1]);if(l[0].length==0) jQuery('<tr><td colspan="3" class="message">none yet.</td></tr>').appendTo(l[1]);}function m(s){if('error_message' in s) jQuery('#api_error').text('API Error: '+s.error_message);}function g(p){jQuery.getJSON('//api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/' + QUESTION_ID + '/answers?page=' + p + '&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter=!.Fjs-H6J36w0DtV5A_ZMzR7bRqt1e', function(s){m(s);s.items.map(function(a){var he = jQuery('<div/>').html(a.body).children().first();he.find('strike').text('');var h = he.text();if (!/cracked/i.test(h) && (typeof a.comments == 'undefined' || a.comments.filter(function(b){var c = jQuery('<div/>').html(b.body);return /^cracked/i.test(c.text()) || c.find('a').filter(function(){return /cracked/i.test(jQuery(this).text())}).length > 0}).length == 0)){var m = /^\s*((?:[^,;(\s]|\s+[^-,;(\s])+).*(0.\d+)/.exec(h);var e = [[n++, m ? m[2]-0 : null], jQuery('<tr/>').append( jQuery('<td/>').append( jQuery('<a/>').text(m ? m[1] : h).attr('href', a.link)), jQuery('<td class="score"/>').text(m ? m[2] : '?'), jQuery('<td/>').append( jQuery('<a/>').text(a.owner.display_name).attr('href', a.owner.link)) )];if(/safe/i.test(h)) safe_list.push(e);else uncracked_list.push(e);}});if (s.items.length == 100) g(p + 1);else{var s=[[uncracked_list, '#uncracked'], [safe_list, '#safe']];for(var i=0;i<2;i++) u(s[i],byscore);jQuery('#uncracked_by_score').bind('click',function(){u(s[0],byscore);return false});jQuery('#uncracked_by_creation').bind('click',function(){u(s[0],bycreation);return false});}}).error(function(e){m(e.responseJSON);});}g(1);</script><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/codegolf/all.css?v=7509797c03ea"><div id="api_error"></div><div class="main"><h3>Uncracked submissions</h3><table> <tr> <th>Language</th> <th class="score">Score</th> <th>User</th> </tr> <tbody id="uncracked"></tbody></table><div>Sort by: <a href="#" id="uncracked_by_score">score</a> <a href="#" id="uncracked_by_creation">creation</a></div></div><div class="main"><h3>Safe submissions</h3><table> <tr> <th>Language</th> <th class="score">Score</th> <th>User</th> </tr> <tbody id="safe"></tbody></table></div>
```

> **Note**
>
> This challenge is finished. The final winner is **feersum** with his [*Seed answer*](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/98599/34388). Congratulations! :).
>
> You can still submit new cops, but be aware that they are no longer competing.

Comment: Do I understand the rules right that if I come up with a 30-byte program and post a 40-byte program, someone who writes a 39-byte program couns as cracking it?

Comment: @xnor Yes, that is correct

Comment: @Andan That seems unfortunate. Say I write a golf with multiple clever tricks that improve on the obvious formula. If I post the obvious formula, anyone can find one improvement and win. Or, I have to tip my hand and give away all the improvements but one. Would you consider changing this, if it's not too late? Sorry for not thinking of this in this sandbox, I only noticed when trying the challenge in earnest.

Comment: @xnor Hmm, that would cause a big problem with the scoring mechanism. You can then make an arbitirarily large submission and an almost impossible short one, and win the challenge.

Comment: @Adnan You could solve that by defining score = len(secret code)/min {len(public code), len(shortest code posted by robbers)}.

Comment: @AndersKaseorg The score doesn't count if a robber has cracked your submission.

Comment: @Adnan The context is xnor’s suggestion to make the score count if the robbers beat your public score but do not match your secret score. I’m proposing a way to make that work while avoiding the problem you’re concerned about.

Comment: If someone cracks my submission, but hasn't found the shortest possible program (the intended solution), can I update the post with a shorter version?

Comment: @xsot I'm going to say no, because that would fall under the last rule of the challenge.

Comment: @AndersKaseorg I'm pretty sure that goes against the rules of a [tag:cops-and-robbers] challenge. That means that you can easily win the challenge by simply submitting a lot of entries.

Comment: Yeah, finally another Cooooops and Rooooobbbbbers challenge.

Comment: If you can golf it any further (public or a secret) could you change the answer?

Comment: @muddyfish In chat, we have decided that you can golf your private answer before you reveal it. Your public answer must remain the same.

Comment: @DerpfacePython For all terms given at OEIS when you press on list after the sequence. (Like [this](https://oeis.org/A005843/list))

Comment: Would it be acceptable to use my new language, [Woefully](https://github.com/Destructible-Watermelon/Woefully)?

Comment: @DestructibleWatermelon You can use it, however it won't be competing since the language postdates the challenge.

Comment: ._. well, does the person who cracks it get points?

Comment: @DestructibleWatermelon Yes, the cracker does receive the points.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

## [Seed](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Seed), 5861 bytes, score = 5012 / 5861 = 0.85

The sequence is primes ([A000040](http://oeis.org/A000040)) with offset 1. a(1) = 2, a(2) = 3, a(3) = 5 etc.

```
106 4339425277766562922902283581834741289660008085947971671079664775075736459902652798498038280771739790213868067702391567527146683746696872737118568202495046682058807677834082334206717794057290386357040004038910321326390033894692316122893125849512049817771469697446796247656883761642659391998672259889315862253584980121050081936190889196979721443972131545258528161479083569474217100401074866410321578452749003295370495810488337344650619973376676577461877392643228932028285261311284691649403036725905675576380944186859525020321196255472295415627414823269713084816196540461818684672201926996228242729726187404845487167114556965625764494860789841409004737497250600337038738035289643512265772877903971230007222865264200102217827010958702813633039465646713707971175729900391272165457566364779628858903697222589748797809421482136725017988969980267265196209027326008642464190920825439635011414535065156799655809935871795742526416544853103823906918352472744460644939241345215614650110978624804796257165525598653433482592675123776747497586586903140407616610040250976121531777891358439091358523224019193934111409521776865798864774150127996987606796522094617839125169013781373842026970010007574244564780540958252950607459585834584855526028427463655493110963000525209314274839412714497954647707284352161251044088451086878301225167181712809612927720502228546704347274977503482518386819117870800284276687560241308964641752876311905619184965236937789822712948719170589044519552259399272657757694404103028213338440810122219269214268424256451648966039627998513353115348057963135398345514276156595104642595820063441019481255889600472121104059631555738973905087895006671206400595057069658845297458058584470727379036742268107372233190371861824194831387484478317333784774872796689435056263039565495723444232483369405079512770383639748492508848098080619713255928884946598796741958520788406091704951276729428229224292748702301286318784744573918534142896761450194446126776354892827260482520089107240497527796383449573487121759294618654056309957794765646022274249211113876873102681817500947681708211056388348991201016699342850495527766741633390367735662514559206616070479934780700857859919517187362382258597709910134111383911258731633002354208155277838257255571878219168563173495861133946240923601273185050088148273459064040178741322137494758164795598458780786653602794809987537740537018415433767449108362051063814315399931951925462073202072886716208053889630274798247936580024665863765351912184189125660586187615847325588786048095120241198943086897428919324650596915625795076460123743259068671341944912206659194476673792489442514470540309819938731582497982088632076086088279435186513066668502875362808653657423813387124496122632219269226944975782747969308509448942429277233562654639293567532567668357917753810024961683829653277391094269518376510962710057956994339018307344554672056556222387849272880157861877494719706801624724491116189525394408237355854147113614645956561900837121715298276123085019204014577395795131906357190097536924932784935203378709529040555114884933996346694363879974847691625806412083107877442577777402405491226347699452398189866905599648314105255526411599513768016126067224570735746339691839657336828937030584950250402550603260483421505256395736457980708347396132620971927806636308105501893575073944959824958733880580825249931469481777083600987966500968473202481877213198175820182125298036242272662171321630056435823478710070315022531849275633515412140708923196338877549535352180465031450246889723670908173572778497329815806296369714467774385173078365517895215622645081749679859298824530173433952201710212962315524645807786760255396609101229899503687886977229729747349967302227815724222900649259120496955396616388023947812556426182596252076072286860171961582235043470190275528327438941205680729222092142315348205283459886659277456757338926863444370956987436702675569004062857510888080701482282900718067707825890168959050535970636214821273965900140346587802750221148933877600652180282267212515086387728695565345543441575183083490091817551421389124038251086513387106526847199935776240422217886407416027185332010280169564289345500368555274327733580514983967396271907637608170801013991375555069570288329399237332712790289521766624379537848996471168926519414464863388365890585061582441222989105844636887033599262856636618609644981203616618819656730174147506366895579518927217154437260067784133452192099436160162797896733220282837763342940047719962882720310397266700665603774047807673735452896542215047419894928360985667680051383584281780118001522220147385455276205847620842066894760474814386271419398361771509559702341442734727141312211989794380570433135781896005067541537095546614638001539678780066976441749790924521292297473522803115912791790379839635473194794843511234906415092857115568242448079933264380632375450234146479596225552359821776361923588178896354011117990551249184457345201223244319766597339520899930287542362386381372955844126876031262062731835081542890548095759704856479235361996156162229417953890962902505112862674541020677153054937034038823204321411753183982406667628845943390275194956321260584953509501973880059966268311741789559039618821364775407403947492157311255310143283125490988585303127442698159113924719563571459841025286208880511134222538431747221840824203312684036627017414295981003169360893015436564680773233890198618904647085929678054127680367983802905553144716598061593632352021737488422700265144189474970515439967472618438343180405852959047054139020095303915498443045344690691354304662161461750826840689185141612937350984288238847592910919431788170821390987459951181698659544772214696392241600642992000900364649438402093845534643663733216626212187314397293309505677932731383013397665193960914949915855970134736764497124186701371371881061763702617034928084811708964018610410971938419410791443362686750151572343348438861493025667676713
```

The Befunge-98 programs were tested with [this interpreter](http://mearie.org/projects/pyfunge/).

Solution:

```
62 92671758747582594731336103958852355343308794409787718910287760272065096600068486400261521203099179296478278113800406388237579729434074471528101978922110199511009255327569364221068648720732186414156697930516237153253745234146558781777104311285708042469572129997820696177040412749585193035961972308024909384538547357820271391461203855177879703963391294547499579588457829374981409596253284387318191154655397249791533591896711203680125312645807793061567274893660125978667479654664977040722935418267606762108334976561590548772755653088127344268269983549959628254712562135604114391709222466418283973346968039685907258341712475120187026707300070769277380483828579629391533415119380882514570806683534933872011332303802477012040660361613689139008855327957705058672774790021218679288003003953301651226513713984857174365383390364296326192225244927665294515693697694918935732394438095829822147927645949273829493190176397786165741955566462476231578299385726525505407052332068778469428870102672560545990553686935179657522071350801304923521681690806124866463401094200444841941834667455137491597902735287855498886460945851544063102556545691787612423033525861765804657417395955322217721677429700032333887700477665924915189639029356029794151144702621112140447347270986003871777552705154393697526621456025974679633450745341583481291685834000335168972075093212539251102818038917942913311300883294570091156661153874804268309393591292001433191276766990017144340677002050765359295580546228905861008474333888247511333039470305173620221481374758754343560048199433044290376988914313248904786418615239832295700238599693805552407166251501198275363727855984193340187485162706203747898935844148656997727555488455764358003951396850496841760348138874901474547533715922587211143833052692993182786162665394965914056238514702648647904702501871758140636318131208564891924287008550289224318358936576352473100482724524675417108540029486047223784009872784235439805791496176981701859374772960623187174667015174831665360382067784289660747175586412802848517818731070091826086320292632019033525579172665790335268736167170506003176022610987557889205903933680970434653929602313812168432779881423599218075810156457004870273456214668951969634696002866863369645150677406566613367576078149751561615160777945725724620047443832859087000460506626402089973036918592151204779260519899343451226942874643654023265001514280212345984966126290887141500898797940093805650642580450926977375576911590855135774911449619005627413806680159169643085790457809525639117624947749945044091079624534522626841372604654172723500062361904864176709974716350878399949908529715899937417421315012456868864220900338162700464737416505300734198857624165994112815507157337074226022552948626042899845891195024145834980781844015548398775284084741665926642729256313545870065439195137107807599897817556866239630270351410298105991743248934632486671734759038305157913444368204353943206369388913837519310828223093441519335111533635957953613758894822654736600526811789875376813119426924959017038654104216784121093688306563643326587639486472221258233221666454164763738631579246841130247019172136121041002571694545781948282785399495873501148416357057693713305042834246973535325571882393889489457235864027134943913383832461393499203435931881991959787045205816313165984531168137210464591653390767999403651750434079431253272021002273680565508340556736474927770564408343360602057949991306130979603289667991356237787412616305022971197507815004141825394838946364485315703051195195566893733123391158803413838803831010122718476800229685100410524315094662633390222854924884579083098055980542607258318868514903610787510921796157291630993618714015755412239872758443166948699744841899868754369627081727143351807615097715679652005998467491609044596871312950634152039807480021814406950780706131231897491212637759991818212542181136384052857191779658528790835620632765143337026858373660057972387266312097135260115742458792764792668883627539340807572869610941154184473111399152964165437112713815173281951728792354570851956468302291939952274005357250989986640723863408051924618400882866539701190471828299028566020683682444415198672952980294639217217840535225987439355834087974716313911977302809235338769491339553247328065401203243450045946392960085318343121705830317674151229536850726617093615850507955559652374337057819549481320081981520577039493601331233500403284295119207704095876958023271178964331413629547646937335760969491450824461526563643617594783473684358594189269252499897162333533284912320654686655888508024970105099967896167541978181602786701854274646885561632089896312016789257459673121974866871919820865433343707787147414982407950775979279255414469970743690769124215210050618943726165676550098723299244096267839544684847323547847832349290874282817429866612456451105673214159820212156069771415582214200701894487126822756864305461967035982308878073752362075553218935807632264803200753661147341613284071218919438723527468202903770806766095252957940538229987302177328543423522712562396242285027178395886649344
```

Comment: This would take centuries to crack o_____O

Comment: *The Right Language for the Challenge* ™

Answer (score 27):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 5 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page), score 0.8 (4 / 5) [[cracked!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/89108/58271)]

```
R²SÆ½
```

Computes [A127721](http://oeis.org/A127721).

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=UsKyU8OGwr0&input=&args=MQ&debug=on)

---

Here's the solution:

```
RÆḊḞ
```

- implicitly take input `n`
- `R`: list from `[1, 2, ..., n]`
- `ÆḊ`: In our case, this will actually return the square root of the sum of squares (which may be useful in future golfing)!
- `Ḟ`: floor the result.

The [documentation](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Atoms) for `ÆḊ` reads:

> `ÆḊ`: Determinant, extended to non-square matrices.

The key is *extended to non-square matrices*. The "determinant" of a non-square matrix is usually undefined, but one reasonable definition is `sqrt(det(A A^T))` (which for a square matrix reduces to `|det(A)|`). In our case, `A A^T` is a 1 x 1 matrix containing the sum of squares. The square root of the determinant of that gives us exactly what we need to shave off the last byte!

Comment: Welcome to Programming Puzzles and Code Golf!

Comment: Just out of curiosity, is this actually possible in 4 bytes? I've been stuck on this for hours :p.

Comment: @Adnan, yes it's possible. Glad to hear you're finding it challenging!

Comment: [Cracked.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/89108/25180)

Comment: @jimmy23013, yup, nicely done!

Answer (score 12):

### [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 28 bytes, score = 0.9286... (26/28), [cracked by feersum](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/89085/8478)

```
.+
$*
^$|^((^|\3)(^.|\1))*.$
```

Computes [A192687](https://oeis.org/A192687), (offset = 0).

[Try it online!](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=JShHYAouKwokKgpeJHxeKChefFwzKSheLnxcMSkpKi4k&input=MAoxCjIKMwo0CjUKNgo3CjgKOQoxMAoxMQoxMgoxMwoxNAoxNQ) (The first line enables a linefeed-separated test suite.)

This is the difference between Hofstadter's [male](https://oeis.org/A005378) and [female](https://oeis.org/A005379) sequences. ([Relevant PPCG challenge.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/80608/8478))

This was my original code:

```
.+
$*
^((^.|\3)(\1)|){2,}$
```

This answer was a bit of a gamble anyway, because the actual solution is based on a regex [I announced to be the shortest known Fibonacci-testing regex](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/240?m=29301239#29301239) in chat a few months ago. Luckily, no one seemed to remember that. :)

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/89085/30688)

Answer (score 12):

### [Stack Cats](https://github.com/m-ender/stackcats), 14 bytes, score = 13 / 14 = 0.929 [[cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/89956)]

That's 10 bytes of code, plus 4 for the arguments  `-nm`.

Computes [A017053](https://oeis.org/A017053). In case OEIS is down, that's `a(n) = 7n + 6`, starting at `n = 0`.

```
![_-_:-_-_
```

The full code (usable without `-m` argument) is `![_-_:-_-_-_-:_-_]!`

The hidden solution was

```
!]|{_+:}_
```

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/89956/21487)

Answer (score 11):

## [Hexagony](https://github.com/m-ender/hexagony), 91 bytes, Score = 0.725274725 (66/91) [[Cracked]](//codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/89095/8478)

Computes [A000045](https://oeis.org/A000045) (Fibonacci sequence, offset 0).

I won't be too surprised if someone manages to beat this and my more golfed version<s>, although it should be hard.</s>

Edit: Holy cow, @MartinEnder whipped me with a 33 byte solution.

Golfed (91):

```
?\]~<~.{>'"/(@{\''1<{!1>{{1}/}{'\1</={}/_\'0"/>+(}\/}(+'+'%=<>=%"=+("\/+"(+}+<>{{}=~\.....|
```

Formatted:

```
      ? \ ] ~ < ~
     . { > ' " / (
    @ { \ ' ' 1 < {
   ! 1 > { { 1 } / }
  { ' \ 1 < / = { } /
 _ \ ' 0 " / > + ( } \
  / } ( + ' + ' % = <
   > = % " = + ( " \
    / + " ( + } + <
     > { { } = ~ \
      . . . . . |
```

[Try it online!](http://hexagony.tryitonline.net/#code=P1xdfjx-Lns-JyIvKEB7XCcnMTx7ITE-e3sxfS99eydcMTwvPXt9L19cJzAiLz4rKH1cL30oKycrJyU9PD49JSI9KygiXC8rIigrfSs8Pnt7fT1-XC4uLi4ufA&input=NQ)

I'm not going to post an explanation for this, it's too horrible...

Golfed (66):

```
?{1}]0@._.>\>+{./'++.!.|.*'}..\}{\=++.../'"<_}\"+<./{(/\=*"=/>{=+"
```

Formatted:

```
      ? { 1 } ] 0
     @ . _ . > \ >
    + { . / ' + + .
   ! . | . * ' } . .
  \ } { \ = + + . . .
 / ' " < _ } \ " + < .
  / { ( / \ = * " = /
   > { = + " . . . .
    . . . . . . . .
     . . . . . . .
      . . . . . .
```

Colored:

[image: Fibonacci sequence]

[Try it online!](http://hexagony.tryitonline.net/#code=P3sxfV0wQC5fLj5cPit7Li8nKysuIS58LionfS4uXH17XD0rKy4uLi8nIjxffVwiKzwuL3soL1w9KiI9Lz57PSsi&input=MTA)

Explanation:

The memory layout I used looks a little like this:

```
   |
   a
   |
  / \
b+a  b
/     \
      |
    input
```

The initialization (in black) sets a=0 and b=1. Then, the main loop:

- goes from `a` to the input cell - `'"`
- decrements the input - `(`
- adds b and a - `{{=+`
- moves it "out of the way" - `"+{=*`
- sets a to b - `'+`
- moves a "out of the way" - `'+}=*`
- moves b+a back to its original position - `"=+`
- sets b to b+a - `"+`
- moves a back to its original position - `}+`

Once the input cell reaches 0, the MP moves to a, prints, and exits.

What I could have done to save more bytes is to use &, which just sets the current cell to either its left or right neighbor. I also could have had a bit better flow control, but it's okay as it stands.

Comment: [Cracked.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/89095/8478) Thanks for getting me to write a Fibonacci program. Not sure why I haven't done that before. :)

Comment: Actually, what I'm using `&` for is to move the input around the a/b/a+b edges so that they swap their roles on the next iteration. That I way, I don't need to move a, b and a+b around at all.

Comment: @MartinEnder Sorry, I wrote that part before looking at what your program actually did. Your solution is much more clever

Answer (score 10):

## [M](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/m), 10 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page), score 0.6 (6 / 10) [[cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/89072/12012)]

```
R‘ạḤc’*@RP
```

A tad cheaty since M and Jelly are quite similar, but allowed by the rules. This version is based on [@LeakyNun's crack](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/89065/12012) to my Jelly answer.

This calculates sequence [A068943](http://oeis.org/A068943). [Try it online!](http://m.tryitonline.net/#code=UuKAmOG6oeG4pGPigJkqQFJQCsOH4oKs&input=&args=MSwgMiwgMywgNCwgNQ)

#### Intended solution

The following code works in M/Jelly.

```
R¹¡PÐL
```

I actually had a 4-byte solution to which I added some fluff to make it seem more difficult to crack by using brute force.

```
R¡FP
```

[Try it online!](http://m.tryitonline.net/#code=UsKhRlA&input=&args=Ng)

This is the one I'm going to explain.

```
R¡FP  Main link. Argument: n

 ¡    Execute the left to the left n times, updating the return value.
R       Range; map each integer k to [1, ..., k].
      This does the following for the first values of n.
        1 → [1]
        2 → [1,2]   → [[1],[1,2]]
        3 → [1,2,3] → [[1],[1,2],[1,2,3]] → [[[1]],[[1],[1,2]],[[1],[1,2],[1,2,3]]]
  F   Flatten the resulting, nested array.
   P  Take the product of the reulting array of integers.
```

Comment: [Cracked!](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/89072/6710) It was fun!

Answer (score 7):

### [Snowman](https://github.com/KeyboardFire/snowman-lang), 50 bytes, score = 0.9 (45 / 50) [[cracked by Lynn](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/89363/3852)]

```
((}#NDe`nOnO|`2nMNdE0nR2aGaZ::nM;aF;aM:nS;aF,nM*))
```

This is a subroutine that takes a number as its argument and returns another number.

Computes [A122649](https://oeis.org/A122649) (offset = 1).

[Try it online!](http://snowman.tryitonline.net/#code=fnZnMTBzQiogLy8gcmVhZCBpbnB1dCBmcm9tIFNURElOIGFuZCBwYXNzIGl0IHRvIHRoZSBzdWJyb3V0aW5lCgooKH0jTkRlYG5Pbk98YDJuTU5kRTBuUjJhR2FaOjpuTTthRjthTTpuUzthRixuTSopKQoKI3RTc1AgICAgLy8gb3V0cHV0IHRoZSByZXR1cm4gdmFsdWUgdG8gU1RET1VU&input=MTA)

Comment: What is the calling convention for so-called "subroutines"?

Comment: [Cracked!](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/89363/3852)

Answer (score 7):

### Haskell, 15 bytes, score = 13/15 (0.866) ([cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/92656/20260))

```
f x=1+2*div x 2
```

[A109613](https://oeis.org/A109613) with offset 0. Repeats each odd number twice.

```
1, 1, 3, 3, 5, 5, 7, 7, 9, 9, 11, 11, 13, 13, ...
```

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/92656/30688)

Answer (score 6):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 27 bytes, score = 0.666... (18/27), [Cracked!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/89021/41723)

```
+ybL:L:[1]co~c[A:B]hl-?,A*.
```

Computes [A010551](https://oeis.org/A010551) (offset = 0).

You can [try it online here](http://brachylog.tryitonline.net/#code=K3liTDpMOlsxXWNvfmNbQTpCXWhsLT8sQSou&input=MTA&args=Wg).

#### Explanation

Since the vast majority of people don't know this language, and since I'm posting this answer mostly to get people looking into it (See: [Brachylog's Wiki](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog/wiki)), I'll provide a short explanation of the code above:

```
+           Add 1 to the input N
ybL         L = [1, 2, ..., N+1]
:L:[1]c     Construct a list [1, 2, ..., N+1, 1, 2, ..., N+1, 1]
o           Sort the list from smallest to biggest
~c[A:B]     A concatenated to B results in that sorted list
hl-?,       The length of A is N + 1
A*.         The output is the result of the product of all elements of A
```

Comment: [Cracked!](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/89021/48934)

Answer (score 6):

### Haskell, 4 bytes / 5 bytes ([cracked by Leaky Nun](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/89046/20260))

Let's start simple. [A000012](https://oeis.org/A000012), the sequence of all 1's (offset 0). Here's a table:

```haskell
0 -> 1
1 -> 1
2 -> 1
3 -> 1
4 -> 1
 ...
```

**5 bytes:**

```haskell
f n=1
```

Comment: [Cracked!](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/89046/48934)

Answer (score 6):

## Java 7, 53 bytes, score = 0.9623 (51/53) [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/89083/58251)

```
int f(int n){return n<1?3:n<2?0:n<3?2:f(n-2)+f(n-3);}
```

Computes the Perrin sequence, [A001608](https://oeis.org/A001608)

```
f(0)=3
f(1)=0
f(2)=2
f(n)=f(n-2)+f(n-3)
```

First code golf attempt, feel free to point out any mistakes.

### Explanation after cracking:

[miles](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/89083/58251) shortened the first three values (0,1,2) -> (3,0,2) to

```
n<2?3-3*n:n<3?2
```

while my own solution was a slightly over-engineered

```
n<3?(n+4)%5*2%5
```

Combining the two tricks, you get

```
n<3?3-3*n%5
```

for a 47-byte

```
int k(int n){return n<3?3-3*n%5:f(n-2)+f(n-3);}
```

which looks pretty compact for Java :)

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/89083/6710)!

Answer (score 5):

### Cheddar, 7 bytes, score = 0.8571 (6/7), [[cracked]](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/89053/40695)

```
n->2**n
```

Pretty simple, just the powers of two. [OEIS A000079](https://oeis.org/A000079)

[Try it online!](http://cheddar.tryitonline.net/#code=bi0-Mioqbg&input=NA)

Comment: Uh, language creators are at an advantage here...

Comment: Especially language creators whose languages are sorely lacking in documentation.

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/89053/30688) (?)

Comment: @Mego is self documenting code not considered docs? The code reviewers lied to me! D:<

Comment: @Downgoat When you have a link on your website called "Documentation" and it's woefully incomplete... Yeah.

Comment: @feersum yup, nice!

Answer (score 4):

## J, 17 bytes, score = 0.8235 (14/17) ([cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/89029/6710))

```
(+/@(!+:)&i.-)@>:
```

Computes [A002478](http://oeis.org/A002478).

The funny thing is that this version was originally the short one to be kept secret.

Comment: [Cracked!](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/89029/7311)

Answer (score 4):

### Pyke, 11 bytes, score = 0.45 (5/11) [[cracked]](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/89116/12012)

```
hZRVoeX*oe+
```

Calculates [OEIS A180255](https://oeis.org/A180255)

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=hZRVoeX%2aoe%2B&input=4)

Comment: I wanted to have a go at this one but the documentation for the language isn't very enlightening. (e.g. `Z` is undocumented; the language claims to be stack-based but after the `*` there are only zeros on the stack despite it having an effect on the rest of the code; order of parameters is not clearly specified)

Comment: @Score_Under what could I do to improve it? - Perfectly happy to discuss in a chat room about what's unclear

Comment: Sure. I don't know how to start a chat but I've edited my above comment with some examples - I thought I'd be able to get it in before you read it ;)

Comment: @Score_Under http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43566/pyke-language

Comment: To anyone else reading, I'll be happy to respond to queries about the language in that chat room (but only when I'm awake)

Comment: [Cracked.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/89116/12012)

Answer (score 4):

## Python 2, 43 bytes, score = 0.9302 (40/43), [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/89022/45268)

`f=lambda n:n==1or-(-sum(map(f,range(n)))/3)`

Computes [A072493](https://oeis.org/A072493)

Let's see if anybody can golf off all 3 bytes.

Comment: Wait, is it really okay if `True` is used to represent `1`?

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/89022/30688)

Comment: `s=1;exec"a=-(-s/3);s+=a;"*input();print a` for 41.

Comment: @R.Kap yes, it is. Any value that is truthy (`if x` is true) is a valid return.

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 9 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page), score 0.5556 (5 / 9) [[cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/89218/12012)]

```
r©0+’Ac®Ḅ
```

This calculates sequence [A119259](http://oeis.org/A119259). [Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=csKpMCvigJlBY8Ku4biECsW8w4figqxH&input=&args=MCwgMSwgMiwgMywgNCwgNSwgNiwgNywgOCwgOSwgMTA)

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/89218/6710), but barely.

Answer (score 4):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 11 bytes, score = 10 / 11 = 0.909, [cracked!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/89320/41723)

```
ybLrb:Lrcc.
```

Computes [A173426](https://oeis.org/A173426).

[Try it online!](http://brachylog.tryitonline.net/#code=eWJMcmI6THJjYy4&input=MTE&args=Wg)

#### Explanation

```
ybL      L = [1, 2, …, Input]
rb       Get [Input - 1, …, 2, 1]
:Lrc     Concatenate [1, 2, …, Input] and [Input - 1, …, 2, 1]
c.       Concatenate [1, 2, …, Input, Input - 1, …, 2, 1] into a single integer
```

Comment: [Cracked!](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/89320/48934)

Answer (score 4):

## J, 20 bytes, score = 0.75 (15/20) ([cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/90411/6710))

```
[:*/0 1(]{:,+/)^:[~]
```

Computes [A001654](http://oeis.org/A001654).

My solution for 15 bytes was

```
*&(+/@:!&i.-)>:
```

Comment: [cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/90411/12012)

Answer (score 3):

## [Sesos](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/sesos), 14 bytes, score = 0.8571 (12/14) ([cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/88989/48934))

```
0000000: 16f8be 760e1e 7c5f3b 07ddc7 ce3f                  ...v..|_;....?
```

Computes [A000290](https://oeis.org/A000290).

[Try it online!](http://sesos.tryitonline.net/#code=c2V0IG51bWluCnNldCBudW1vdXQKZ2V0CmptcCxzdWIgMSxmd2QgMSxhZGQgMSxmd2QgMSxhZGQgMSxyd2QgMixqbnoKZndkIDEKam1wCiAgc3ViIDEsZndkIDEKICBqbXAsc3ViIDEsZndkIDEsYWRkIDEsZndkIDEsYWRkIDEscndkIDIsam56CiAgZndkIDEKICBqbXAsc3ViIDEscndkIDEsYWRkIDEsZndkIDEsam56CiAgcndkIDIKam56CmZ3ZCAzCnB1dA&input=MTI&debug=on)

#### Hints

This binary file has been generated by the following assembler:

```lisp
set numin
set numout
get
jmp,sub 1,fwd 1,add 1,fwd 1,add 1,rwd 2,jnz
fwd 1
jmp
  sub 1,fwd 1
  jmp,sub 1,fwd 1,add 1,fwd 1,add 1,rwd 2,jnz
  fwd 1
  jmp,sub 1,rwd 1,add 1,fwd 1,jnz
  rwd 2
jnz
fwd 3
put
```

Comment: [Cracked!](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/88989/3852)

Answer (score 3):

### [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 11 bytes, score = 0.8181 (9/11), [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/89030/36398)

```
YftdA-1bn^*
```

Computes the [Möbius function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_function), or [A087811](https://oeis.org/A008683) (offset 1).

[Try it online!](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=WWZ0ZEEtMWJuXio&input=MTA)

#### Resources for robbers

I think this one should be easy, but anyway here is some help.

Code explanation:

```
Yf     % Implicit input. Push array of prime factors, with repetitions
t      % Duplicate
d      % Compute consecutive differences
A      % 1 if all those differences are nonzero, 0 otherwise
-1     % Push -1
b      % Bubble up array of prime factors to the top of the stack
n      % Number of elements
^      % -1 raised to that
*      % Multiply. Implicitly display
```

Language [documentation](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL/tree/master/doc).

MATL [chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39466/matl-chatl).

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/89030/30688)

Comment: @feersum Well done! For reference, the 9-byte version was [`YftdA_wn^`](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=WWZ0ZEFfd25e&input=MTA)

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 11 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page), score 0.5455 (6 / 11) [[cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/89065/12012)]

```
Ḷ+’cḶ
r1*ÇP
```

This calculates sequence [A068943](http://oeis.org/A068943). [Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=4bi2K-KAmWPhuLYKcjEqw4dQCsW8w4figqxH&input=&args=MSwgMiwgMywgNCwgNQ)

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/89065/48934)

Answer (score 3):

### [MarioLANG](http://esolangs.org/wiki/MarioLANG), 87 bytes, score = 0.839 (73/87), [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/89213/53880)

```
;
)-)+(< >>
-)===" ""====
>>+([!)( >-(+(
"====#[(("== [
!-) - <!!![)<<)
#======###====:
```

Computes [A000217](https://oeis.org/A000217), the triangular numbers. Offset 0.

[Try it online!](http://mariolang.tryitonline.net/#code=OwopLSkrKDwgPj4KLSk9PT0iICIiPT09PQo-PisoWyEpKCA-LSgrKAoiPT09PSNbKCgiPT0gWwohLSkgLSA8ISEhWyk8PCkKIz09PT09PSMjIz09PT06&input=NQ)

#### Short Solution:

Since the crack took only 1 byte off, I'll share my solution in 73 bytes, which uses a different algorithm altogether:

```
;   +)-<
-   (=="
+)-<(
(=="+
> [!>)[!(
"==#===#[
!    -  <))
#=========:
```

[Try it online!](http://mariolang.tryitonline.net/#code=OyAgICspLTwKLSAgICg9PSIKKyktPCgKKD09IisKPiBbIT4pWyEoCiI9PSM9PT0jWwohICAgIC0gIDwpKQojPT09PT09PT09Og&input=NQ)

**The first program** lays out all the numbers from n to 1 along the tape, then adds up all numbers until it comes across a 0-value cell. It does this by copying each cell into the two adjacent cells, decrementing the right copy, and repeating the process on it until it reaches 0. During this process, the tape looks like this (for n=5):

```
0 0 5 0 0 0 0
0 5 0 5 0 0 0
0 5 0 4 0 0 0
0 5 4 0 4 0 0
0 5 4 0 3 0 0
0 5 4 3 0 3 0
0 5 4 3 0 2 0
0 5 4 3 2 0 2
```

... and so on. Then it moves left, summing the cells until it reaches a cell with 0.

**The second program** only works with three cells of the tape. Until the first cell reaches 0, it does the following:

- Move the value of the first cell to the second cell.
- Decrement the second cell to 0, adding its own value to the first and third cells.
- Decrement the first cell.

After the first cell reaches 0, the third cell will contain n + (n-1) + (n-2) + ... + 2 + 1.

Comment: Does your 87 byte version work in another interpreter? The one on Tio! seems to require a trailing newline...

Comment: @Dennis: It does work on the Ruby interpreter without the newline. For whatever reason, the interpreter on TIO won't output from a `:` if it's on the bottom line, which is why I included the trailing newline in the link. Martin and I discussed this in another one of my MarioLANG answers.

Comment: OK, just checking. I've added wrapper for Tio! that appends a newline to the source code.

Comment: [cracked I think (not sure though)](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/89213/55896)

Answer (score 3):

## [M](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/m), 18 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page), score 0.3889 (7 / 18) [[cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/90544/12012)]

```
r0+c
‘Ḥc0r$×Ç:‘+\S
```

This approach is based on [@Sp3000's golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/88981/can-you-outgolf-me-robbers-section#comment220362_90340) of my Jelly answer.

The code calculates sequence [A116881](http://oeis.org/A116881) (row sums of **CM(1,2)**). [Try it online!](http://m.tryitonline.net/#code=cjArYwrigJjhuKRjMHIkw5fDhzrigJgrXFMKMHIxMMOH4oKsauKBtyAgICAgICDhuLfigJwgVGVzdCBzdWl0ZS4gUnVucyB0aGUgYWJvdmUgbGluayBmb3IgaW5wdXRzIDAgdG8gMTAu&input=)

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/90544/30688)

Answer (score 3):

### Haskell, 28 bytes, score = 0.3571 (10/28), [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/97131/20260)

```
f n|odd n=1|1>0=2*f(div n 2)
```

[A006519](https://oeis.org/A006519), the highest power of 2 dividing `n`, starting at `n=1`.

```
1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 8, 1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 16, 1, ...
```

While you get cracking credit for any shorter code, I consider the real puzzle to be getting down to 10 bytes.

Comment: [my try](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/97131/34531).

Comment: @nimi Congrats, you got it.

Answer (score 2):

### [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 9 bytes, score = 0.6667 (6/9), [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/89002/47066)

```
ÐnŠ·sÉO4/
```

Computes: [A087811](http://oeis.org/A087811)

[Try it online](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=w5BuxaDCt3PDiU80Lw&input=MjU)

Comment: [Cracked!](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/89002/48934)

Answer (score 2):

## [Hexagony](http://github.com/mbuettner/hexagony), 7 bytes, score = 0.857 (6/7), [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/89013/8478)

Not designed to be the winning submission, but definitely a brain cracker. It actually isn't that hard if you think about it :p. Code:

```
\!?__@(
```

Or a more readable version:

```
 \ !
? _ _
 @ (
```

Computes [A052246](https://oeis.org/A052246).

[Try it online!](http://hexagony.tryitonline.net/#code=XCE_X19AKA&input=Nw).

Comment: [Cracked,](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/89013/8478)

Answer (score 2):

## J, 10 bytes, score = 0.9 (9/10) ([cracked by Dennis](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/89057/48934))

```
*2%~3<:@*]
```

Computes [A000326](http://oeis.org/A000326).

This one should be easy.

[Online interpreter](http://tryj.tk/).

[Quickref](http://code.jsoftware.com/wiki/NuVoc).

Comment: [Cracked.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/89057/12012)

Answer (score 2):

## J, 9 bytes, score = 0.6667 (6/9) ([cracked by Dennis](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/89056/48934))

```
9 o.0j1^]
```

Computes [A056594](http://oeis.org/A056594).

Comment: [Cracked.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/89056/12012)

Comment: @Dennis dang, you beat me to it.

Answer (score 2):

### [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 7 bytes, score = 0.571 (4/7), [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/89137/47066)

```
0s·Ì3c;
```

Computes: [A006331](http://oeis.org/A006331)

[Try it online](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=MHPCt8OMM2M7&input=Nw)

After golfing 5 unique versions of this sequence before finding this public version I hope I haven't left any obvious improvement out there so it'll at least be a challenge for the robbers.

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/89137/9288).

Answer (score 2):

## [M](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/m), 9 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page), score 0.6667 (6 / 9) [[cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/89760/12012)]

```
r©0+’Ac®Ḅ
```

A tad cheaty since M and Jelly are quite similar, but allowed by the rules. [@miles' crack](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/89218/12012) to my Jelly answer doesn't work in M; it lacks the `œċ` atom.

This calculates sequence [A119259](http://oeis.org/A119259). [Try it online!](http://m.tryitonline.net/#code=csKpMCvigJlBY8Ku4biECsW8w4figqxq4oKs4oG2auKBtw&input=&args=MCwgMSwgMiwgMywgNCwgNSwgNiwgNywgOCwgOQ)

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/89760/30688)

Comment: I had started to hope this one would survive... Well done.

Answer (score 2):

### QBasic (QB64), 30 bytes, score = 28 / 30 = 0.9333 ([cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/90346/30688))

```
INPUT n:p=n MOD 2:?p*n+(n+p)/2
```

Computes [A014682](http://oeis.org/A014682), a version of the Collatz function (offset 0).

This works on the [QB64](http://qb64.net) emulator with autoformatting turned off. It *should* work on actual QBasic as well, but I don't have a copy to test it.

---

My 28-byte version used a bitwise operator and integer division:

```
INPUT n:?(1AND n)*n+(n+.5)\2
```

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/90346/30688)

Comment: So "integer division" is floating-point division followed by round to nearest? Funny :)

Comment: @feersum Even curiouser, actually: it appears to be round to nearest followed by integer division. For example, `1.4\2` gives `0`, but `1.6\2` gives `1`. I can't confirm whether that's how it works in actual QBasic or if it's a QB64 quirk, but it's weird, in any case.  ... Which just made me realize that I could have used `1` instead of `.5`, for 27 bytes.  D'oh!

Answer (score 2):

### *[Acc!!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/62493/16766)*, 526 bytes, score = 0.5627 (296/526) ([cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/90451/16766))

```
N
Count x while _%60-46 {
(_+_%60*5-288)*10+N
}
_/60
Count i while _/27^i {
_+27^i*(_/27^i*26-18)
}
_*3+93
Count i while _/27^i/27%3 {
_-i%2*2+1
Count j while _/3^(3*j+2-i%2)%3 {
_+3^(1+i%2)
Count k while _/3^(3*k+1+i%2)%3-1 {
_+3^(3*k+1+i%2)*26
}
}
}
Count i while _/27^i/3 {
_-_/27^i/3%27*27^i*3+_/3^(3*i+1+_%3)%3*3
}
_/3
Count i while _/100^i {
_+_/100^i*100^i*9
}
Count i while _/100^i/10 {
_+_/100^i/10%10
Count j while i+1-j {
_+(_%10-_/100^(j+1)%10)*(100^(j+1)-1)
}
}
_/100
Count j while _/100^j {
Write _/100^j%10+48
}
```

Computes [A000204](http://oeis.org/A000204), Lucas numbers with offset 1.

A couple of notes. Due to *Acc!!*'s input limitations, the program takes input as a decimal number terminated with a period (`.`); for example:

```
> python acc.py Program.txt
5.
11
```

This program has exponential time complexity, so I wouldn't recommend running it with input greater than about 14 (takes 60 seconds on my laptop). However, *given enough time*, the algorithm will return the correct result for any positive integer *n*. Thus: **a crack attempt that places any size limits on the input value is invalid**.

Have fun!

Comment: [cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/90451/12012) (barely)

Answer (score 2):

### Python, 46 bytes, score = 0.97826 (45 / 46) [[cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/90490/21487)]

```py
f=lambda n,k=1:n and-~f(n-("01"in bin(k)),k+1)
```

Calculates [A101082](http://oeis.org/A101082) (offset = 1), which are:

> Numbers n such that binary representation contains bit strings "10" and "01" (possibly overlapping).

---

@Dennis cracked the submission as intended, which was to replace `"01"in bin(k)` with some bit twiddling, namely `(k&-k)+k&k>0`, to check that `k`'s binary representation isn't of the form `111...111000...000`.

Comment: [cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/90490/12012)

Answer (score 2):

### [*Acc!!*](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/62493/16766), 512 bytes, score = 0.5625 (288 ÷ 512) ([cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/91290/16766))

Fourth try. Let's see how fast Dennis cracks this one. *(Edit: 8 minutes, that's a record!)*

```
N
Count x while _%60-46 {
(_+_%60*5-288)*10+N
}
_/30
Count i while _/27^i {
_+(_/27^i*26-18)*27^i
}
_*3+93
Count i while _/27^i/27%3 {
_-i%2*2+1
Count j while _/3^(3*j+2-i%2)%3 {
_+3+i%2*6
Count k while _/3^(3*k+1+i%2)%3-1 {
_+27^k*3^(i%2)*78
}
}
}
Count i while _/27^i/3 {
_-_/27^i/3%27*27^i*3+_/3^(3*i+1+_%3)%3*3
}
_/3
Count i while _/100^i {
_*10-_%100^i*9
}
Count i while _/100^i/10 {
_+_/100^i/10%10
Count j while i+2-j {
_+(_%10-_/100^j%10)*(100^j-1)
}
}
_/100
Count j while _/100^j {
Write _/100^j%10+48
}
```

Computes [A002878](http://oeis.org/A002878), Lucas(2*n+1), offset = 0.

Due to *Acc!!*'s input limitations, the program takes input as a decimal number terminated with a period (`.`); for example:

```
> python acc.py Program.txt
3.
29
```

This program has exponential time complexity, so I wouldn't recommend running it with input greater than about 7. However, *given enough time*, the algorithm will return the correct result for any positive integer *n*. Thus: **a crack attempt that places any size limits on the input value is invalid**.

Comment: [cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/91290/12012)

Comment: @Dennis Hey, fastest yet!

Answer (score 2):

## [Woefully](https://github.com/Destructible-Watermelon/Woefully), (noncompeting, but you still get points for cracking it), <s>520/776= ~0.67</s> Cracked by Feersum.

Computes [A000042](http://oeis.org/A000042) (would compute repunits, but that one has 0 as first member)

Offset 1, zero indexed (0 outputs 1, 1 outputs 11, 2 outputs 111, etc.)

```
| |||||||| | |
|| |||||| |
||| |||| |
|||| || |
||||| || |
|||| |||| |
||| |||||| |
|| |||||||| |
| |||||||||| |
|| ||||||||| |
||| |||||||| |
|||||||||||| |
|||||||||||| |
|||||||||||| |
||||||||||| |
|||||||||| |
|||||||||| |
|||||||||| |
|||||||||| |
||||||||||| |
|||||||||||| |
||||||||||||| |
|||||||||||| |
||||||||||| |
|||||||||| |
||||||||| |
|||||||| |
||||||| |
|||||| |
||||| |
|||| |
||| |
|| |
|| |
|| |
| |
| |
| |
| |
| |
|| |
|| |
|| |
||| |
|||| |
||||| |
|||||| |
||||||| |
|||||||| |
||||||| |
|||||||| |
||||||||| |
|||||||||| |
||||||||||| |
|||||||||||| |
||||||||||||| |
|||||||||||| |
||||||||||| |
|||||||||| |
||||||||| |
|||||||| |
||||||| |
|||||| |
||||| |
|||| |
||| |
|| |
|| |
|| |
|| |
||| |
|||| |
||| |
|| |
| |
| |
| |
|| |
|| |
|| |
|| |
```

[Try it online!](http://woefully.tryitonline.net/#code=fCB8fHx8fHx8fCB8IHwKfHwgfHx8fHx8IHwKfHx8IHx8fHwgfAp8fHx8IHx8IHwKfHx8fHwgfHwgfAp8fHx8IHx8fHwgfAp8fHwgfHx8fHx8IHwKfHwgfHx8fHx8fHwgfAp8IHx8fHx8fHx8fHwgfAp8fCB8fHx8fHx8fHwgfAp8fHwgfHx8fHx8fHwgfAp8fHx8fHx8fHx8fHwgfAp8fHx8fHx8fHx8fHwgfAp8fHx8fHx8fHx8fHwgfAp8fHx8fHx8fHx8fCB8Cnx8fHx8fHx8fHwgfAp8fHx8fHx8fHx8IHwKfHx8fHx8fHx8fCB8Cnx8fHx8fHx8fHwgfAp8fHx8fHx8fHx8fCB8Cnx8fHx8fHx8fHx8fCB8Cnx8fHx8fHx8fHx8fHwgfAp8fHx8fHx8fHx8fHwgfAp8fHx8fHx8fHx8fCB8Cnx8fHx8fHx8fHwgfAp8fHx8fHx8fHwgfAp8fHx8fHx8fCB8Cnx8fHx8fHwgfAp8fHx8fHwgfAp8fHx8fCB8Cnx8fHwgfAp8fHwgfAp8fCB8Cnx8IHwKfHwgfAp8IHwKfCB8CnwgfAp8IHwKfCB8Cnx8IHwKfHwgfAp8fCB8Cnx8fCB8Cnx8fHwgfAp8fHx8fCB8Cnx8fHx8fCB8Cnx8fHx8fHwgfAp8fHx8fHx8fCB8Cnx8fHx8fHwgfAp8fHx8fHx8fCB8Cnx8fHx8fHx8fCB8Cnx8fHx8fHx8fHwgfAp8fHx8fHx8fHx8fCB8Cnx8fHx8fHx8fHx8fCB8Cnx8fHx8fHx8fHx8fHwgfAp8fHx8fHx8fHx8fHwgfAp8fHx8fHx8fHx8fCB8Cnx8fHx8fHx8fHwgfAp8fHx8fHx8fHwgfAp8fHx8fHx8fCB8Cnx8fHx8fHwgfAp8fHx8fHwgfAp8fHx8fCB8Cnx8fHwgfAp8fHwgfAp8fCB8Cnx8IHwKfHwgfAp8fCB8Cnx8fCB8Cnx8fHwgfAp8fHwgfAp8fCB8CnwgfAp8IHwKfCB8Cnx8IHwKfHwgfAp8fCB8Cnx8IHw&input=Mw)

---

I like to think that my shorter solution was a pretty nice one.

```
| || || |
|| || |
||| || |
|||| || |
||||| || |
|||| |||| |
||| ||||| |
|| |||||| |
| ||||||| |
|| |||||| |
||| ||||| |
||| |||| |
|||| || |
||| ||| |
|| |||| |
| ||||| |
|||||||| |
||||||||| |
|||||||||| |
|||||||||| |
||||||||| |
|||||||| |
||||||| |
|||||| |
||||| |
||||| |
||||| |
|||| |
|||| |
|||| |
|||| |
|||| |
||| |
||| |
||| |
|||| |
|||| |
||||| |
||||| |
|||||| |
||||| |
|||| |
||| |
|| |
| |
| |
| |
| |
|| |
||| |
||| |
|||| |
||| |
|| |
| |
| |
| |
|| |
|| |
|| |
|| |
||| |
||| |
|||| |
||| |
|| |
| |
```

What I did was remove the push one command from the top, replace it at the bottom and at the end of the first command, which was free because I just had to replace some pipes, which then allowed me to shorten the push nine commands some more, because it didn't need to move that much anymore

Comment: This TIO link is way too long o_o

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/92673/30688)

Answer (score 2):

## J, 12 bytes, score = 0.9167 (11/12) ([cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/92825/30688))

```
(#++/)@I.@#:
```

Computes [A230877](http://oeis.org/A230877).

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/92825/30688)

Answer (score 2):

## J, 18 bytes, score = 0.7222 (13/18) ([cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/94808/6710))

```
0{]1&(}.],+/)2 1"_
```

Computes the Lucas numbers, [A000032](http://oeis.org/A000032).

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/94808/30688)

Answer (score 1):

## [Sesos](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/sesos), 14 bytes, score =  0.6429 (9/14) ([cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/88992/48934))

```
0000000: aed40b b47bc2 8e01be 8e9ddb b107                  ....{.........
```

Computes [A130909](http://oeis.org/A130909).

[Try it online!](http://sesos.tryitonline.net/#code=c2V0IG51bWluCnNldCBudW1vdXQKYWRkIDE2LGZ3ZCAxLGdldApqbXAKICBzdWIgMSxyd2QgMixhZGQgMSxmd2QgMSxzdWIgMQogIGptcCxyd2QgMixqbnoKICByd2QgMQogIGptcCxqbXAsc3ViIDEsZndkIDEsYWRkIDEscndkIDEsam56LHJ3ZCAyLGpuegogIGZ3ZCA0Cmpuegpyd2QgMgpwdXQ&input=NTI&debug=on)

Comment: [Cracked again](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/88992/3852) :>

Comment: You need to include the score in the header of your submission.

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3.5, 38 bytes, Score = 0.86842 (33/38) ([Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/89025/52405)):

```
G=lambda n:n<1and 1or(2*n-1)**2*G(n-1)
```

Computes [A001818](https://oeis.org/A001818).

[Try It Online! (Ideone)](http://ideone.com/2CpTuF)

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/89025/30688)

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](http://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 10 bytes, score = 5 ÷ 10 = 0.5, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/89093/3852)

This one isn't too hard actually :p. Code:

```
[NNÂÊ½¾¹Q#
```

Computes the **N**<sup>th</sup> **non-palindromic number**, which is [A029742](http://oeis.org/A029742).

[Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=W05Ow4LDisK9wr7CuVEj&input=NDU)

Comment: [Cracked.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/89093/3852)

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6), 77 bytes, score = 0.9481 (73 / 77) [[Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/89122/30688)]

```js
n=>eval("for(i=0;n;a||n--)[...s=a=++i+''].map(d=>a-=Math.pow(d,s.length));i")
```

Computes [A005188](https://oeis.org/A005188), (offset = 1).

---

Didn't end up being super interesting but I thought I'd try and submit something.

*Note: This is in **ES6** so there is no `**` operator. I just thought this would make it more cross-browser compatible and easier to test.*

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/89122/30688)

Comment: @feersum Lol, I should have spent more time golfing it! Evidently this is possible in 72 bytes...

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](http://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 13 bytes, score = 0.769 (10 ÷ 13), [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/89142/47066)

This one isn't too hard either. Code:

```
µN•vÉ•vyK}g_½
```

Calculates [A001742](https://oeis.org/A001742) (offset = 1).

[Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=wrVO4oCidsOJ4oCidnlLfWdfwr0&input=MTE).

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/89142/47066). Gonna keep working on that 10 byte solution for a while.

Answer (score 1):

**Python (3.4.3), 77 bytes, score = 0.7272 (56/77) [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/89159/51393)**

```
import math;lambda x: 1 if x==0 else (0 if ((math.sqrt(1+8*x)-1)/2)%1 else 1)
```

Computes [A010054](https://oeis.org/A010054), offset = 0

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/89159/30688)

Answer (score 1):

## Coffeescript, 83 bytes, score = 79/83 = 0.952 [[cracked!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/88981/can-you-outgolf-me-robbers-section/89228#89228)]

```coffee
r=(n)->return if r<0 then 0 else Array(parseInt(n/9)+2).join ((n-1)%9+1).toString()
```

Computes [A010785](http://oeis.org/A010785).

(Not so) Surprisingly, @DomHastings managed to shave 33 bytes off of my solution.

Wow, I suck at [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), don't I? Well, here's my other code:

```coffee
r=(n)->return if r<0 then 0 else ((n-1)%9+1).toString().repeat(parseInt(n/9)+2)
```

Here's a less messy version of the code:

```coffee
r=(n)->
  if r<0
   return 0 
  else 
   ((n-1)%9+1).toString().repeat(parseInt(n/9)+2)
   # ((n-1)%9+1).toString() is the repeating digit (as a string).
   # parseInt(n/9)+2 is the times the digit is repeated.
```

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/89228).

Answer (score 1):

### [Pip](http://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 24 bytes, score = 22 / 24 = 0.9166 ([cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/90363/16766))

```
Y53T++i>ay.:k.A(yi)A(ya)
```

Computes [A109648](http://oeis.org/A109648) (offset = 0). [Try it online](http://pip.tryitonline.net/#code=WTUzVCsraT5heS46ay5BKHlpKUEoeWEp&input=&args=Mg)!

---

My 22-byte version:

```
T++v>alPB A(lJk|5v)l@a
```

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/90363/30688)

Answer (score 1):

### [Actually](https://github.com/Mego/Seriously), 28 bytes, Score = 0.39285714 (11/28) ([cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/89838/45941))

```
2√;;4*;u@D))u(*,;)@ⁿ)1-*ⁿ@-½
```

Computes [A048696](https://oeis.org/A048696) (offset = 0). Actually uses [CP437](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437) for its encoding.

[Try it online!](http://actually.tryitonline.net/#code=MuKImjs7NCo7dUBEKSl1KCosOylA4oG_KTEtKuKBv0Atwr0&input=MQ)

Dennis's solution is *actually* almost identical to mine:

```
19,`;τ(+`nX (Dennis)
19(`;)τ+`nX (Mine)
```

A Levenshtein distance of 3 is pretty impressive!

[Try it online!](http://actually.tryitonline.net/#code=MTkoYDspz4QrYG5Y&input=MA)

Comment: [cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/89838/12012)

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 22 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page), score 0.2727 (6 / 22) [[cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/90340/12012)]

```
‘ðḤ;+;c2\×P:+’×$¥µÐ€‘S
```

This calculates sequence [A116881](http://oeis.org/A116881). [Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=4oCYw7DhuKQ7KztjMlzDl1A6K-KAmcOXJMKlwrXDkOKCrOKAmFMKMHIxMMK1xbzDh-KCrEcgICAgICAgICAgICAgIOG4t-KAnCBUZXN0IHN1aXRlLiBSdW5zIHRoZSBhYm92ZSBsaW5rIGZvciBpbnB1dHMgMCB0byAxMC4&input=)

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/90340/30688)

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](http://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 7 bytes, score = 0.857 (6 / 7) [[cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/90461/47066)]

This one shouldn't be too hard if you think about it :p. Code:

```
L!zO¹!*
```

[Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=TCF6T8K5ISo&input=Ng)

Computes [A002627](https://oeis.org/A002627).

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/90461/47066)

Answer (score 1):

### *[Acc!!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/62493/16766)*, 523 bytes, score = 0.55067 (288/523) ([cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/90480/12012))

Second try, slightly different sequence.

```
N
Count x while _%60-46 {
(_+_%60*5-288)*10+N
}
_/60
Count i while _/27^i {
_+27^i*(_/27^i*26-18)
}
_*3+93
Count i while _/27^i/27%3 {
_-i%2*2+1
Count j while _/3^(3*j+2-i%2)%3 {
_+3^(1+i%2)
Count k while _/3^(3*k+1+i%2)%3-1 {
_+3^(3*k+1+i%2)*26
}
}
}
Count i while _/27^i/3 {
_-_/27^i/3%27*27^i*3+_/3^(3*i+1+_%3)%3*3
}
_/3
Count i while _/100^i {
_*10-_%100^i*9
}
Count i while _/100^i/10 {
_+_/100^i/10%10
Count j while i+1-j {
_+(_%10-_/100^(j+1)%10)*(100^(j+1)-1)
}
}
_/100
Count j while _/100^j {
Write _/100^j%10+48
}
```

Computes [A000032](http://oeis.org/A000032), Lucas numbers with offset 0.

Due to *Acc!!*'s input limitations, the program takes input as a decimal number terminated with a period (`.`); for example:

```
> python acc.py Program.txt
5.
11
```

This program has exponential time complexity, so I wouldn't recommend running it with input greater than about 14 (takes 60 seconds on my laptop). However, *given enough time*, the algorithm will return the correct result for any positive integer *n*. Thus: **a crack attempt that places any size limits on the input value is invalid**.

Comment: [cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/90480/12012)

Answer (score 1):

### *[Acc!!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/62493/16766)*, 522 bytes, score = 0.5555 (290 ÷ 522) ([cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/90482/16766))

Third try. Thanks to Dennis for the golfing "help" with the first two. ;^)

```
N
Count x while _%60-46 {
(_+_%60*5-288)*10+N
}
_/60*2
Count i while _/27^i {
_+(_/27^i*26-18)*27^i
}
_*3+93
Count i while _/27^i/27%3 {
_-i%2*2+1
Count j while _/3^(3*j+2-i%2)%3 {
_+3+i%2*6
Count k while _/3^(3*k+1+i%2)%3-1 {
_+27^k*3^(i%2)*78
}
}
}
Count i while _/27^i/3 {
_-_/27^i/3%27*27^i*3+_/3^(3*i+1+_%3)%3*3
}
_/3
Count i while _/100^i {
_*10-_%100^i*9
}
Count i while _/100^i/10 {
_+_/100^i/10%10
Count j while i+1-j {
_+(_%10-_/100^(j+1)%10)*(100^(j+1)-1)
}
}
_/100
Count j while _/100^j {
Write _/100^j%10+48
}
```

Computes [A005248](http://oeis.org/A005248), Lucas(2*n), offset = 0.

Due to *Acc!!*'s input limitations, the program takes input as a decimal number terminated with a period (`.`); for example:

```
> python acc.py Program.txt
3.
18
```

This program has exponential time complexity, so I wouldn't recommend running it with input greater than about 7. However, *given enough time*, the algorithm will return the correct result for any positive integer *n*. Thus: **a crack attempt that places any size limits on the input value is invalid**.

Comment: [cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/90482/12012)

Answer (score 1):

## Excel, 16 bytes, score = 0.75, [[cracked by Dennis♦](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/90491/58742)]

```
=FACTDOUBLE(2*n)
```

Computes [**A000165**](http://oeis.org/A000165)**:** double factorial of even numbers, (offset = 0).

Comment: [Cracked?](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/90491/12012)

Comment: This answer doesn't have the correct form -- it is not a program or a function.

Comment: @feersum By the definition [here](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/2073/58742), it is a program

Comment: See [here](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods). Input by inserting the number into the source code isn't an accepted input method.

Comment: @feersum No need to insert the number into the code, but you can use name of reference cell `n` as an input

Comment: What do you mean? How do I specify the input?

Comment: @feersum Name the cell input as `n`. See [this](http://www.excel-easy.com/examples/names-in-formulas.html)

Answer (score 1):

## [INTERCAL](http://www.catb.org/%7Eesr/intercal/), <s>85 bytes</s> Score: 77/85=0.90588, safe.

Input: up to `SIX FIVE FIVE THREE FIVE`, although actual calcuatable input is smaller than that.

This calculates [A000217](https://oeis.org/A000217).

```
PLEASEWRITEIN.1PLEASE.2<-#1DO(1000)NEXTDO.2<-.3DO(1030)NEXTDO.3<-.3~#65534DOREADOUT.3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8wrSS1KTsz5/z/Ax9Ux2DU8yDPE1dNPzxDC1TOy0VU2dPHXMDQwMND0c40IcfEHiekZg8WM4WLGILE6ZTNTU2MTF/8gV0cX/9AQPeP///39XBWiXIP8uQA)

### The answer

77 bytes.

```
PLEASEWRITEIN.2PLEASE.1<-.2DO(1020)NEXTDO(1030)NEXTDO.3<-.3~#65534DOREADOUT.3
```

C-INTERCAL has a subroutine that just increments .1, which is (1020).

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8wrSS1KTsz5/z/Ax9Ux2DU8yDPE1dNPzwjC1TO00dUzcvHXMDQwMtD0c40IAbONYWw9Y6C8cZ2ymampsYmLf5Cro4t/aIie8f///n6uClGuQf5cAA)

Comment: I'm on UTC+9, so would I be safe at 20:48 here?

Comment: Calcuable up to `TWO FIVE FIVE`

Answer (score 0):

## Python, 39 bytes, 26/39=2/3=0.666 cont. points, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/88996/48934)

```
s=lambda x:x+s(x-1)if x==1else x+s(x-1)
```

won't last long, but lets see just how long. Just doing the robbers a favour I guess (also because I don't know eso golf langs ;_;)

umm, I accidentally bad code but someone cracked my lower score so...

computes [A000217](https://oeis.org/A000217)

Comment: How does this terminate if the then clause and the end clause are the same?

Comment: Which version of Python is this?

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/88996/48934).

Comment: You need to include the score in the header :3.

Comment: also o sh*t I did the wrong code :(

Answer (score 0):

### Python, 69 bytes, score = 0.97 (67÷69), [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/89270/12012)

```
f=lambda n:reduce(lambda x,y:x*y,range(1,n+1),1)
lambda n:f(n*2)/f(n)
```

Computes [A001813](https://oeis.org/A001813)

Comment: [cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/89270/12012)

Answer (score 0):

## 05AB1E - 1 byte - [A000027](https://oeis.org/A000027)

Code: `I`

## 05AB1E - 0 bytes - [A000027](https://oeis.org/A000027)

Code:

Explanation:

`I` means that it pushes the input to the stack.

means that nothing is changed to the stack, but the input was already added to the stack by default, so it prints out the input.

Comment: Please note this challenge has been inactive for 2 years.

Comment: Oh I thought that there was a proposal to revive old challenges