# Hofstadter Q-sequence

Tags: code-golf, sequence, arithmetic

## Definition

1. a(1) = 1
2. a(2) = 1
3. a(n) = a(n-a(n-1)) + a(n-a(n-2)) for n > 2 where n is an integer

## Task

Given positive integer `n`, generate `a(n)`.

## Testcases

```
n  a(n)
1  1
2  1
3  2
4  3
5  3
6  4
7  5
8  5
9  6
10 6
11 6
12 8
13 8
14 8
15 10
16 9
17 10
18 11
19 11
20 12
```

## Reference

- Obligatory OEIS [A005185](http://oeis.org/A005185)

Comment: [Related](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/41593/48934).

Comment: [Related answer.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/35611/8478)

Comment: Can we return *True* in languages where it can be used as **1**?

Comment: @Dennis If in that language true is equivalent to 1 then yes.

Comment: Apart from the OEIS link it might be good to reference GEB where the sequence first appeared.

Comment: [Related](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/80608/36398)

Comment: [Completing the list of GEB-related sequence challenges.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/37529/8478)

Comment: You could probably translate the problem description into Haskell by only adding a few characters.

Comment: What input does it have to support up to?

Comment: That´s not Leonard Hofstadter, is it?

Answer (score 10):

## Haskell, <s>35</s> 33 bytes

```
a n|n<3=1|b<-a.(-)n=b(b 1)+b(b 2)
```

Defines a function `a`.

Comment: Nice trick with the bind! Wouldn't something like `(b.b)1+(b.b)2` be shorter than the sum?

Comment: Why yes, thanks @xnor.

Answer (score 9):

### [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), <s>84</s> <s>83</s> <s>79</s> 74 bytes

Byte count assumes ISO 8859-1 encoding.

```
.+
$*;1¶1¶
+`;(?=(1)+¶(1)+)(?=(?<-1>(1+)¶)+)(?=(?<-2>(1+)¶)+)
$3$4¶
G3=`
1
```

[Try it online!](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=JShHYAouKwokKjsxwrYxwrYKK2A7KD89KDEpK8K2KDEpKykoPz0oPzwtMT4oMSspwrYpKykoPz0oPzwtMj4oMSspwrYpKykKJDMkNMK2CkczPWAKMQ&input=MQoyCjMKNAo1CjYKNwo4CjkKMTA) (The first line enables a linefeed-separated test suite.)

I'll have to golf this some more later.

Answer (score 8):

## Julia, 29 bytes

```julia
!n=n<3||!(n-!~-n)+!(n-!~-~-n)
```

[Try it online!](http://julia.tryitonline.net/#code=IW49bjwzfHwhKG4tIX4tbikrIShuLSF-LX4tbikKCmZvciBuIGluIDE6MjAKICAgIEBwcmludGYoIiUydSAtPiAlMnVcbiIsIG4sICFuKQplbmQ&input=)

#### How it works

We redefine the unary operator `!` for our purposes.

If **n** is **1** or **2**, `n<3` returns *true* and this is our return value.

If **n** larger than **2**, `n<3` returns *false* and the *||* branch gets executed. This is a straightforward implementation of the definition, where `~-n` yields **n - 1** and `~-~-n` yields **n - 2**.

Answer (score 7):

## Sesos, 54 bytes

```
0000000: eefb5b 04f83a a75dc2 36f8d7 cf6dd0 af7b3b 3ef8d7  ..[..:.].6...m..{;>..
0000015: cfed12 f661f0 ae9d83 ee63e6 065df7 ce6183 af7383  ....a.....c..]..a..s.
000002a: 76ef3c 3f6383 7eff9c b9e37f                       v.<?c.~.....
```

[Try it online](http://sesos.tryitonline.net/#code=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&input=MjA&debug=on)

#### Disassembled

```
set numin
set numout
add 1
fwd 1
add 1
fwd 6
get
sub 1
jmp
    jmp
        sub 1
        fwd 1
        add 1
        rwd 1
    jnz
    fwd 1
    sub 1
    rwd 2
    add 2
    jmp
        rwd 4
        jmp
            sub 1
            fwd 3
            add 1
            rwd 3
        jnz
        fwd 4
        jmp
            sub 1
            rwd 3
            add 1
            rwd 1
            add 1
            fwd 4
        jnz
        rwd 3
        jmp
            sub 1
            fwd 3
            add 1
            rwd 3
        jnz
        fwd 4
        add 2
        jmp
            rwd 5
            jmp
                rwd 1
                jmp
                    sub 1
                    fwd 2
                    add 1
                    rwd 2
                jnz
                fwd 1
                jmp
                    sub 1
                    rwd 1
                    add 1
                    fwd 1
                jnz
                rwd 1
                sub 1
            jnz
            fwd 2
            jmp
                sub 1
                rwd 1
                add 1
                rwd 1
                add 1
                fwd 2
            jnz
            fwd 1
            jmp
                rwd 2
                jmp
                    sub 1
                    fwd 1
                    add 1
                    rwd 1
                jnz
                fwd 2
                jmp
                    sub 1
                    rwd 2
                    add 1
                    fwd 2
                jnz
                fwd 1
            jnz
            fwd 3
            sub 1
        jnz
        rwd 2
        jmp
            sub 1
            rwd 3
            add 1
            fwd 3
        jnz
        fwd 1
        sub 1
    jnz
    fwd 2
jnz
rwd 7
put
```

Or in Brainfuck notation:

```
+>+>>>>>>,-[[->+<]>-<<++[<<<<[->>>+<<<]>>>>[-<<<+<+>>>>]<<<[->>>+<<<]>>>>++[<<<<<[<
[->>+<<]>[-<+>]<-]>>[-<+<+>>]>[<<[->+<]>>[-<<+>>]>]>>>-]<<[-<<<+>>>]>-]>>]<<<<<<<.
```

Answer (score 6):

## C, <s>43</s> 42 bytes

*Saved 1 byte thanks to @Dennis*

Every answer is the same, I must do something different!

[Try it online!](https://ideone.com/yuS2JB)

```c
a(n){return n<3?:a(n-a(n-2))+a(n---a(n));}
```

Explanation: it's basically `a(n-a(n-2))+a(n-a(n-1))` but with swaggy<sup>undefined</sup>behavior (works on my phone (gcc) and ideone).

Comment: 1. You should also mention the compiler; your "swag" is undefined behavior. 2. With GCC, you don't need the `1` between `?` and `:`.

Comment: @Dennis Interestingly, that same formulation works in my iterative PowerShell answer... `$b+=$b[$_-$b[$_-2]]+$b[$_---$b[$_]]`

Comment: @TimmyD some compilers may compile the a(n) before the n--, and there isn't a standart (or defined) behavior for that. Thus, undefined behavior.

Comment: @betseg Yep, I agree. Just pointing out that it's not necessarily unique to C.

Comment: @TimmyD Oh I misunderstood that. I just wanted to change the function that everybody uses, so mine would be different and swaggy :D

Comment: …If you just want to be different, you could use `~-n == n-1` rather than relying on undefined behavior.

Answer (score 5):

### Mathematica, 36 bytes

Byte count assumes ISO 8859-1 encoding and Mathematica's `$CharacterEncoding` set to `WindowsANSI` (the default on Windows; other settings might work as well, but some like `UTF-8` definitely don't).

```
±1=±2=1
±n_:=±(n-±(n-1))+±(n-±(n-2))
```

Defines `±` as a unary operator.

I tried getting rid of the duplication, but ended up with the same byte count:

```
±1=±2=1
±n_:=Tr[±(n-±(n-#))&/@{1,2}]
```

Comment: I may give you a +200 bounty if you do it in Retina

Comment: @LeakyNun okay? :)

Comment: Two days later.

Comment: @LeakyNun Soon you're going to have no rep left if you give out bounties so easily.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43248/discussion-between-legionmammal978-and-martin-ender).

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>15</s> 14 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
2Rạ⁸ß€$⁺Sµ1>?2
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=MlLhuqHigbjDn-KCrCTigbpTwrUxPj8y&input=&args=MTA) or [verify all test cases](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=MlLhuqHigbjDn-KCrCTigbpTwrUxPj8yCjIwUsK1xbzDh-KCrEc&input=) (takes a few seconds).

#### How it works

```
2Rạ⁸ß€$⁺Sµ1>?2  Main link. Argument: n (integer)

2R              Yield [1, 2].
      $         Combine the previous three links into a monadic chain.
   ⁸                Yield n.
  ạ                 Take the absolute difference of the return value and n.
    ß€              Recursively call the main link on each result.
       ⁺            Duplicate the chain.
                    The first copy maps [1, 2] to [a(n - 1), a(n - 2)].
                    The second copy maps [a(n - 1), a(n - 2)] to
                    [a(n - a(n - 1)), a(n - a(n - 2))].
        S           Take the sum.
         µ          Combine all links to the left into a chain.
            ?       If...
           > 2          n is greater than 2, call the chain.
          1         Else, return 1.
```

Comment: I may give you a +400 bounty if you do it in Sesos.

Comment: @LeakyNun There seems to be an Sesos answer. It came out one day after your comment.

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>14</s> <s>12</s> 11 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
ịḣ2S;
1Ç⁸¡2ị
```

This is an iterative approach.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@/9wd/fDHYuNgq25DA@3H1poBOT////fyAAA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@/9wd/fDHYuNgq25DA@3P2rccWihEVDov5FB0KGtR/cAhZrWuP8HAA).

#### How it works

```
1Ç¡2ị   Main link. Argument: n

1       Set the return value to 1.
 Ç¡     Call the helper link n times, updating the return value after each call.
   2ị   Extract the second element of the resulting array.


ịḣ2S;   Helper link. Argument: A (array)

ị       At-index; retrieve the elements of A at the values of A.
 ḣ2     Head 2; extract the first two results.
    S   Take the sum of the result.
     ;  Prepend the sum to A.
```

Answer (score 4):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>45 Bytes</s> 34 Bytes

A recursive solution in ES6. Any golfing tips much appreciated.

```
a=n=>n>2?a(n-a(n-1))+a(n-a(n-2)):1
```

Thank you to [/u/ismillo](http://reddit.com/u/ismillo) for shortening even further.

Answer (score 3):

## Python, <s>45</s> 40 bytes

```py
a=lambda n:n<3or a(n-a(n-1))+a(n-a(n-2))
```

Simple naïve interpretation of the challenge.

*Saved 5 bytes thanks to @LeakyNun!*

Answer (score 3):

## Haskell, <s>39</s> 37 Bytes

```
h n|n<3=1|n>2=h(n-h(n-1))+h(n-h(n-2))
```

exactly like described in the challenge, using guards

Comment: Sorry, I didn't saw your solution before posting my (identical) haskell solution. However isn't the byte count 38 as the new-line has to be taken into account?

Comment: And the guard has to be `n<3` for `h 2 ` to be `1`.

Comment: @Laikoni It's 37 according to Pythons len feature with a multiline (""") string, unless you count newline as two bytes. Yeah, I noticed the other thing it's fixed now.

Comment: TIL notepad++ counts newline as two character.

Comment: @Laikoni got rid of the newline it's indisputably 37 bytes now.

Comment: @Laikoni In windows a newline is quite often represented as `\r\n`, while `\n` is sufficient.

Comment: @flawr Good to know.

Comment: I thought we're allowed to [count the newlines as singles](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/167/line-break-formats-and-character-numbers/168#168) always.

Answer (score 3):

### C#, <strike>51</strike> 44 bytes

```
int a(int n)=>n<3?1:a(n-a(n-1))+a(n-a(n-2));
```

<strike>i wonder if this can be shortened by making it anonymous</strike>
thanks pinkfloydx33!

Comment: c# 6 expression bodied function `int a(int n)=>n<3?1:a(n-a(n-a))+a(n-a(n-2));`

Comment: Seems I typod while typing that on my phone. The inner most `-a` in the first set of parens should be `-1`

Comment: I didn't notice it either, ill fix it rq

Answer (score 3):

## R, 50 bytes

```
a=function(n)ifelse(n<3,1,a(n-a(n-1))+a(n-a(n-2)))
```

Usage:

```
> a(1)
  1
> a(20)
  12
```

Answer (score 3):

### CJam, <s>19</s> 18 bytes

```
XXri{_($2$$+}*]-3=
```

[Try it online!](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=XXri%7B_(%242%24%24%2B%7D*%5D-3%3D&input=20)

Uses the iterative approach.

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby, 36 bytes

A direct implementation. Any golfing suggestions are welcome.

```ruby
a=->n{n<3?1:a[n-a[n-1]]+a[n-a[n-2]]}
```

Comment: Afaik, you can get rid of the a=. If you post it here, it suffices when your code starts with the ->. It counts as an anonymous function then.

Comment: @Seims Unfortunately, as the function calls itself with `a[n-1]` and such, the function needs to be named.

Answer (score 2):

## Golfscript, 29 bytes

```
~[1 1]{..0=(=\..1=(=@+\+}@*2=
```

[Try it online!](http://golfscript.tryitonline.net/#code=flsxIDFdey4uMD0oPVwuLjE9KD1AK1wrfUAqMj0&input=MjA)

Answer (score 2):

### Java 7, <del>68</del> <del>61</del> 51 bytes

17 saved thanks to Leaky Nun.

```
int a(int n){return n<3?1:a(n-a(n-1))+a(n-a(n-2));}
```

Comment: Welcome to PPCG!

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! You might like [Tips for Golfing in Java](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/6671/tips-for-golfing-in-java). An alternate form would be: `int a(int n){return n<3?1:a(n-a(n-2))+a(n---a(n));}`, but unfortunately it uses the same amount of bytes as the answer you already have.. Also, I would specify that your answer is in Java 7, since the Java 8 answer would be shorter: `n->return n<3?1:a(n-a(n-1))+a(n-a(n-2))` (**39 bytes**).

Comment: Thanks for the welcomes guys, and thanks for the tip on Java8 - I didn't realize lambdas were allowed like that - although they're allowed like that in Python, so I guess I just never thought about it. Does the lambda need a semi-colon?

Comment: @JustinTervay I don't use Java 8 a lot, but from what I've heard the semi-colon isn't counted on single-line expressions, according to a comment by *@DavidConrad* and *@CAD97* in [one of my own Java answers](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/87262/52210).

Answer (score 2):

### 05AB1E, 29 bytes

An iterative solution.

```
XˆXˆÍL>v¯¤ys-è¯y¯yÍè-è+ˆ}¯¹<è
```

[Try it online](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=WMuGWMuGw41MPnbCr8KkeXMtw6jCr3nCr3nDjcOoLcOoK8uGfcKvwrk8w6g&input=MTY)

Answer (score 2):

## APL, 20 bytes

```
{⍵≤2:1⋄+/∇¨⍵-∇¨⍵-⍳2}
```

Explanation:

```
{⍵≤2:1⋄+/∇¨⍵-∇¨⍵-⍳2}
 ⍵≤2:1               If argument is 2 or less, return 1
      ⋄              Otherwise:
               ⍵-⍳2  Subtract [1, 2] from the argument
             ∇¨      Recursive call on both
           ⍵-        Subtract both results from the argument     
         ∇¨          Recursive call on both again
       +/            Sum
```

Answer (score 2):

## VBA Excel 87 bytes

Non-recursive, since I want this to work for n=100000, say:

```
Function A(N):ReDim B(N):For i=3 To N:B(i)=B(i-B(i-1)-1)+B(i-B(i-2)-1)+1:Next:A=B(N)+1
```

... and press `return` (byte #87) at the end of the line to get the `End Function` statement for "free". Note that B values are offset by -1 to avoid initializing for n=1 and 2.

Invoke in spreadsheet as normal, eg `=A(100000)` to get `48157`

The recursive version, **61 bytes**,

```
Function Y(N):If N<3 Then Y=1 Else Y=Y(N-Y(N-1))+Y(N-Y(N-2))
```

starts to get unreasonably slow for n>30, and couldn't be said to work at all for n>40.

Comment: We don't care about performance. We care about code length. You should move your shorter solution to the top of your answer.

Comment: @mbomb007 Since I'm nowhere near winning the golf, I'll make my own choices on what constitutes a working program. Not able to handle even single byte integers is not good enough as far as I'm concerned, when there is a solution which can do so easily.

Answer (score 2):

## [Oasis](http://github.com/Adriandmen/Oasis), <s>9</s> <s>7</s> 5 bytes

<s>**Non-competing**, since the language postdates the challenge.</s> Thanks to **Kenny Lau** for saving 4 bytes. Code:

```
ece+V
```

Expanded form (`V` is short for `11`):

```
a(n) = ece+
a(0) = 1
a(1) = 1
```

Code:

```
e        # Stack is empty, so a(n - 1) is used, and it calculates a(n - a(n - 1))
 c       # Calculate a(n - 2)
  e      # Calculate a(n - a(n - 2))
   +     # Add up
```

[Try it online!](http://oasis.tryitonline.net/#code=ZWNlK1Y&input=&args=MTAwMA). Calculates n = 1000 in 0.1 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

### PowerShell v2+, <s>85</s> <s>79</s> 69 bytes

```
param($n)$b=1,1;2..$n|%{$b+=$b[$_-$b[$_-1]]+$b[$_-$b[$_-2]]};$b[$n-1]
```

Takes input `$n`, sets `$b` to be an array of `@(1, 1)`, then enters a loop from `2 .. $n`. Each iteration we tack onto `$b` the latest calculation in the sequence with a simple `+=` and the definition of the sequence. We then output the appropriate number from `$b` (with a `-1` because arrays in PowerShell are zero-indexed). This works if `$n` is `1` or `2` because both of those values are pre-populated into the lower indices of `$b` from the start, so even if the loop tacks on junk, it's ignored anyway.

---

#### Recursive solution <s>78</s> 76 bytes

```
$a={param($k)if($k-lt3){1}else{(&$a($k-(&$a($k-1))))+(&$a($k-(&$a($k-2))))}}
```

First time I've used the equivalent of a lambda as the answer, as usually an iterative solution is shorter (as you can see from all the nested parens). <s>But, in this case, the nested parens are almost duplicated in the iterative solution with the nested array calls, so the recursive solution is shorter.</s> Nope, the iterative solution is indeed shorter (see above).

Call it via the execution-operator, like `&$a 20`. Just a straight-up recursive call.

Answer (score 1):

## Maple, <s>43</s> 41 bytes

```
a:=n->`if`(n>2,a(n-a(n-1))+a(n-a(n-2)),1)
```

Usage:

```
> a(1);
  1
> a(20);
  12
```

This problem is certainly a good candidate for memoization. Using [option cache](https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/maple/view.aspx?path=CacheOption), the run times are cut down significantly:

```
aC := proc(n) 
      option cache; 
      ifelse( n > 2, aC( n - aC(n-1) ) + aC( n - aC(n-2) ), 1 ); 
end proc:
```

This can be seen using:

```
CodeTools:-Usage( aC(50) );
```

Answer (score 1):

### JavaScript (ES6), 66 bytes

```
n=>[...Array(n+1)].reduce((p,_,i,a)=>a[i]=i<3||a[i-p]+a[i-a[i-2]])
```

Non-recursive version for speed; recursive version is probably shorter but I'll leave it for someone else to write. I always like it when I get to use `reduce`. Note: 1 byte saved by returning `true` (which casts to `1` when used in an integer context) for of `a(1)` and `a(2)`.

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth, 16 bytes

```
L|<b3smy-bytdtBb

L                  def y(b):
 |<b3                b < 3 or …
      m      tBb       map for d in [b - 1, b]:
       y-bytd            y(b - y(d - 1))
     s                 sum
```

Defines a function `y`.

[Try it online](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=L%7C%3Cb3smy-bytdtBbyMS20)
(added `yMS20` to print the first 20 values)

Answer (score 1):

## Forth, 76 bytes

I finally got it working!

```
: Q recursive dup dup 3 < if - 1+ else 2dup 2 - Q - Q -rot 1- Q - Q + then ;
```

[**Try it online**](http://ideone.com/b8uJSr)

**Explanation:**

```
: Q recursive                           \ Define a recursive function Q
    dup dup 3 <                         \ I moved a dup here to golf 2 bytes
    if                                  \ If n < 3, return 1
        - 1                             \ Golf: n-n is zero, add one. Same as 2drop 1+
    else
        2dup 2 - Q - Q                  \ Copy n until 4 on stack, find Q(n-Q(n-2))
        -rot                            \ Move the result below 2 copies of n
        1- Q - Q +                      \ Find Q(n-Q(n-2)), then add to previous ^
    then ;
```

[**Try it online**](http://ideone.com/PmnJRO) (slightly un-golfed from above)

Unfortunately, [mutual recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_recursion) is a bit [too wordy](https://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/forth/gforth/Docs-html/Calls-and-returns.html) to use for golfing.

Answer (score 1):

### Lua, 59 bytes

```lua
function a(n)return n<3 and 1 or a(n-a(n-1))+a(n-a(n-2))end
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 17 bytes

```
!¡λṁ!¹m≠→L¹↑_2)ḋ3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASoA1f9odXNr//8hwqHOu@G5gSHCuW3iiaDihpJMwrnihpFfMinhuIsz////MTU)

Feels too long. I'll post something with `fix` soon.

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 20 bytes

No big shenanigans, just recursively calculates the result.

```
§2?1:ßU-ßUÉ)+ßU-ßU-2 
§2                   // If the input is less than or equal to 2
  ?1                 // return 1,
    :                // otherwise
     ß               // recursively recall with
      U-ßUÉ          // input minus recursive recall input minus one
           )+        // plus
             ßU-ßU-2 // same with input minus two.
```

[Try it here.](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=pzI/MTrfVS3fVckpK99VLd9VLTI=&input=MTU=)

Comment: [15 bytes](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=pzKqMvVA31Ut31UtWMN4&input=MTU)

Answer (score 0):

## J, <s>29</s> 28 bytes

```
1:`(+&$:/@:-$:@-&1 2)@.(2&<)
```

Uses the recursive definition.

#### Usage

Extra commands are used for formatting multiple input/output.

```
   f =: 1:`(+&$:/@:-$:@-&1 2)@.(2&<)
   (,:f"0) >: i. 20
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
1 1 2 3 3 4 5 5 6  6  6  8  8  8 10  9 10 11 11 12
```

#### Explanation

```
1:`(+&$:/@:-$:@-&1 2)@.(2&<)  Input: n
                        2&<   If n < 2
1:                              Return 1
                              Else
               -&1 2            Subtract [1, 2] from n to get [n-1, n-2]
            $:@                 Call recursively on n-1 and n-2
           -                    Subtract each of the results from n
        /@:                     Reduce using
      $:                          A recursive call on each
    +&                            Then summation
                                Return that value as the result
```

Answer (score 0):

## dc, 62 bytes

```
?si2sa1dd2:a:a[la1+dsadd1-;a-;alad2-;a-;a+r:ali;a0=A]dsAxli;af
```

This solution makes use of arrays and recursion.

```
?si          # Take input from stdin and store it in register `i'
2sa          # Initialise register `a' with 2, since we'll be putting in the first
             #   two values in the sequence
1dd2         # Stack contents, top-down: 2 1 1 1
:a           # Pop index, then pop value: Store 1 in a[2]
:a           # Ditto:                     Store 1 in a[1]
[            # Open macro definition
 la 1+ dsa   # Simple counter mechanism: Increment a and keep a copy on stack

# The STACK-TRACKER(tm): Top of stack will be at top of each column, under the
#   dashed line. Read commands from left to right, wrapping around to next line.
#   This will be iteration number n.
  dd   1-    ;a       -          ;a            la            d          
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------
# n    n-1   a[n-1]   n-a[n-1]   a[n-a[n-1]]   n             n          
# n    n     n        n          n             a[n-a[n-1]]   n          
# n    n     n                                 n             a[n-a[n-1]]
#                                                            n          
#                                                                       

  2-            ;a            -             ;a            +      r    :a
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------
# n-2           a[n-2]        n-a[n-2]      a[n-a[n-2]]   a[n]   n      
# n             n             a[n-a[n-1]]   a[n-a[n-1]]   n      a[n]   
# a[n-a[n-1]]   a[n-a[n-1]]   n             n                           
# n             n                                                       

 li;a        # Load index of target element, and fetch that element's current value
             #    Uninitialised values are zero
 0=A         # If a[i]==0, execute A to compute next term
]dsAx        # Close macro definition, store on `A' and execute
li;a         # When we've got enough terms, load target index and push value
f            # Dump stack (a[i]) to stdout
```

Comment: In conclusion, if anyone is building an IDE for `dc`, let me know!

Answer (score 0):

## Erlang, 46 bytes

```
f(N)when N<3->1;f(N)->f(N-f(N-1))+f(N-f(N-2)).
```

Answer (score 0):

## Racket, 63 bytes

```rkt
(define(a n)(if(> n 2)(for/sum([m'(1 2)])(a(- n(a(- n m)))))1))
```

Answer (score 0):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 65+2 = 67 bytes

```
^n;
.+]{0$
v1}\
v2} @2->1[
v3}>-  /:::1-1[
>4}:2)?^~~1]{0$.
/0$1[
```

Input neds to be present on the stack at program start, so +2 bytes for the `-v` flag. [Try it online!](http://fish.tryitonline.net/#code=Xm47Ci4rXXswJAp2MX1cCnYyfSBAMi0-MVsKdjN9Pi0gIC86OjoxLTFbCj40fToyKT9efn4xXXswJC4KLzAkMVs&input=&args=LXYgMjA)

More ridiculously slow recursive madness. Test case for 20 on TIO takes 20.5 seconds, so use larger inputs at your own risk

Answer (score 0):

## Clojure, 86 bytes

```clj
(defn a[n](cond(< 0 n 3)1 1(+(a(- n(a(dec n))))(a(- n(a(- n 2)))))))
```

Very literal.

```clj
(defn a [n]
  (cond
    (< 0 n 3) 1 ; Return 1 if n is 1 or 2
    :else (+ (a (- n (a (dec n)))) ; Else, recurse 4 times and do some math
             (a (- n (a (- n 2)))))))

(doseq [n (range 1 21)]
  (println n (a n)))

1 1
2 1
3 2
4 3
5 3
6 4
7 5
8 5
9 6
10 6
11 6
12 8
13 8
14 8
15 10
16 9
17 10
18 11
19 11
20 12
```

Comment: I think you can get rid of the `0` in the `<` statement, because the challenge specs state that the input is a positive integer.

Comment: @Qwerp-Derp ohh, thanks. I'll fix that when I get on my laptop.

Answer (score 0):

### [Lithp](https://github.com/andrakis/node-lithp), 70 bytes

```
(def a #N::((if(<= N 2)(1)((+(a(- N(a(- N 1))))(a(- N(a(- N 2)))))))))
```

Warning: incredibly slow. Very recursive. Implements the exact algorithm in challenge.

[Try it online!](https://andrakis.github.io/lithp-webide/?code=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)

An alternate solution that is much faster, using caching of results:

### [Lithp](https://github.com/andrakis/node-lithp), 166 bytes

```
((def a #N::((if(<= N 2)(1)((+(b(- N(b(- N 1))))(b(- N(b(- N 2)))))))))(var C(dict))
 (def b(scope #N::((if(!(dict-present C N))((dict-set C N(a N))))(dict-get C N)))))
```

[Try it online!](https://andrakis.github.io/lithp-webide/?code=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)

Comment: Just curious, why did you make functions like `(def a #N::(+ N 1))`, where `a` is a successor?

Comment: I'm sorry I don't quite understand you. What do you mean by successor?

Comment: A successor function is a function that increments a number, but that's besides the point. I'm just curious about the way to define functions in Lithp - why did you choose to do `#arg::` when defining functions? I haven't really seen that done in a Lisp-like before.

Comment: Ah, thank you. Firstly, `lowercase` names are atoms. Names beginning with an uppercase are variables. It follow Erlang's design in this way. Next, I struggled to read most Lisp code, though I loved the elegance of it. The way I've designed my syntax is to be easy to read, and an anonymous function (format: `#[Args,...] :: ( calls .. )`) was easy to see what arguments are being passed.
It's only sort-of Lisp-like really. I like the elegance of the braces, and it's easy to parse.

Comment: Oh, that's how it works, thanks! I was looking at the arguments and it seemed a bit weird, but now that you've explained it I can understand why it's like that.

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, 56 bytes

```php
function q($n){return$n<3?:q($n-q($n-1))+q($n-q($n-2));}
```

recursive function; requires PHP 5.6 or later (or replace `?:` with `?1:`).

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-N`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 14 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

Note that the `-N` flag isn't *strictly* necessary here as it would seem returning `true` instead of `1` is allowed.

```
§2ªCìx@ßU-ßXnU
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LU4&code=pzKqQ%2bx4QN9VLd9YblU&input=OA) or [run all test cases](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=pzKqQ%2bx4QN9VLd9YblU&footer=K1Q&input=WzEgMiAzIDQgNSA2IDcgOCA5IDEwIDExIDEyIDEzIDE0IDE1IDE2IDE3IDE4IDE5IDIwXS1t)

```
§2ªCìx@ßU-ßXnU     :Implicit input of integer U
§2                 :Less than or equal to 2?
  ª                :Logical OR with
   C               :12
    ì              :To digit array
     x             :Reduce by addition
      @            :After passing each X through the following function
       ß           :  Recursive call with argument
        U-         :    U minus
          ß        :      Recursive call with argument
           XnU     :        U minus X
```